# libPayPalEC.a without uniqueIdentifier?

Tags: ios, paypal

today I've tried to send my updated app and the apple declined my app for using uniqueIdentifier. After some research I found, that libPayPalEC.a is using uniqueIdentifier 3 times.

Via terminal: strings .Lib/PayPal/libPayPalEC.a | grep uniqueIdentifier

Does any one now where I can download updated library? I was looking everywhere...

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some reasearch and great answer on github: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/13#issuecomment-17882240 I've removed paypal library, removed deviceToken generation and the PayPal mobile is working!

**How to use PayPal payment without library:**

You need to create the payment process on the backend (like PHP) and in the iOS app just open the web view with URL to your backend. To process success or error handle the web view request so you can catch link like error, cancel or success (the pages, which the backend redirects).

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *urlString = [[request.URL absoluteString] lowercaseString];
    if (urlString.length > 0) {
        //80 is the default HTTP port.
        //The PayPal server may add the default port to the URL.
        //This will break our string comparisons.
        if ([request.URL.port intValue] == 80) {
            urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":80" withString:@""];
        }
        NSLog(@"URL %@",urlString);
        if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"success"].location != NSNotFound) {
            // handle error
            if (visible) {
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:complete];
            } else {
                dismissOnAppear = YES;
            }

            return FALSE;
        } else if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"cancel"].location != NSNotFound) {
            // handle error

            if (visible) {
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:complete];
            } else {
                dismissOnAppear = YES;
            }

            return FALSE;
        } else if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"error"].location != NSNotFound) {
            // handle error
            if (visible) {
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:complete];
            } else {
                dismissOnAppear = YES;
            }
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

On the backend handling you don't need to sent dirt token (from the iOS library) any more, you just work with token from paypal as the standard way.

As the payment method use _express-checkout not _express-checkout-mobile and don't send drt as deviceToken.

Comment: You answered that you have removed the function. which function is removed ? I also want to implement the MECL. I get the empty token id.

Comment: can you help with a more specific solution?

Comment: you remove all the library and just open url address where you display the PayPal process (PHP). That's all.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the issue here on github: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/13

Comment: unfortunately its MPL version and not the Express Checkout libPayPalEC.a

Comment: what about Mobile Express Checkout Library ?

Comment: it's been discontinued. You don't need the Mobile Express Checkout library. Just use Express checkout in Webview - which is what we call as Mobile Express Checkout.