# App rejected for accessing Device UDID?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I had a first version of my app already in iStore. Now I want to upload a next version of my app with some bug fixes and new UI. When submitting this time, in the process of uploading zip file in application loader, its started to pass some steps.But after a while I am getting some error like,

1. App should not use uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice and
2. App uses non-public API.So ask me to remove those and re-upload.

So for the first point, started analysing my code and not using UDID method.Some S.O question suggests, even third party code also may use this method.Then I used this command

`$ find . | grep -v .svn  | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep uniqueIdentifier`

to find and its shown two API- Google Analytics and Paypal(MECL).GA is not used now in my app, so I removed but I need paypal fucntionality.So How can I remove this issue from this API.

Then for the 2nd issue, I using the following API in my app
FBConnect,XML Parser,PegexKitLite,ASIHTTPRequest,iCarousel,JSON,MECL(Paypal),Reachability,ZBarSDK and Google analytics. Among these API's I can't find which is non-Public API.

Please share your ideas.Any help will be appreciated.

Note: Even in first version of my app, I used all the above API and it wan successfully passed the apple review.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about the version number change?

Comment: Ya that and all I modified, if you see my question, its rejected because of using uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice class in some API?Any solution for this?

Comment: +1, @NSUserDefault Have you found any success ?? Looking for the same.

Comment: @Mangesh Actually Google Analytics API(the older version), Paypal API contains uniqueIdentifier method.Since GA is not useful for my project, I simply removed it.But Paypal haven't released their latest version, So just I implemented dummy ,uploaded in store(Since my app is only a demo version) and apple accepted my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app is rejected because of Paypal (MECL) library, it uses a `uniqueIdentifier`. I have also asked question about that and i got the reply from PayPal person , but still the issue is not resolved. But you can check the track with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432866/libpaypalmpl-a-is-using-uniqueidentifier-and-apple-reject-reject-the-app). See the answer of **mettler** from PayPal.

Comment: Hi thanks for your valuable response.Have you solved your problem? I downloaded new API from the link given in that S.O and there is no libPayPalEC.a library and methods in PayPal.h also differs.

Comment: In new libpaypalmpl.a i found uniqueIdentifier. so it's not solved. M waiting for new update ...

Comment: Is there any other option for integrating paypal in our app since we are in a urgent to upload our new version?

Comment: Ho create.. currently now I am using express checkout process.So I will make call to server and my server will call Paypal gateway.My server will contains sellar datail.So now I should have the sellar detail within my app, Right?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Analytics v2b4, make sure you dont include and compile

> libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a

in your project.