# Mobile Express Checkout Paypal

Tags: ios, ios6, paypal, paypal-sandbox

With the reject of **libPaypalEC.a** by Apple. There is any alternative to get the token from PayPal without being through the use of the library?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to use Paypal for? Depending on its purpose Apple will not allow you to use it.

Comment: it s for physical products... in that case it will have no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to implement the payment process through the Express Checkout, 
so there is no need to use the lib.

Answer (score 1):

Are you still using the old MPL? That isn't supported anymore. You may want to look into using the iOS SDK:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/

I did a bit of research and found an old post with pretty much the same answer:
[libpaypalmpl.a is using uniqueidentifier and apple reject reject the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432866/libpaypalmpl-a-is-using-uniqueidentifier-and-apple-reject-reject-the-app)

I hope that works for you.

Comment: i can't used PayPal SDK because i am outside USA.